# change authoryear biblatex citation style

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'd like to change the authoryear citations using `\parencite`, so that authors appear as:

```
(AUTHOR, year) and/or (AUTHOR, year, p.) (one page) (AUTHOR, year, pp.) (multiple pages)
```

So far I managed to change last names to uppercase (not my choice, but I'm trying to implements this) in citations and in the bibliography using:

```
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}


\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
{\MakeUppercase{#1}%
\ifblank{#3}{}{\addcomma\space #3}}
{\ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}%
\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
{\addcomma\space}
{}}
```

I have also tried to change multi-author delimiters in-text `\parencite` citations using

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{;\space}
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{;\space}
```

So that references look like:

```
(AUTHOR1; AUTHOR2; AUTHOR3, year).
```

But it didn't work.

I would also like to set all multi-author names as last-first in the references list, separated by semicolons, but the following didn't work either:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
```

I'm using the following in my preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setsansfont{Candara}
\setmonofont{Consolas}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{brazil}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=historian,doi=false,citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{brazil}{namedash={---},volumeof={de},url={Disponível em: }}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}


\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
{\MakeUppercase{#1}%
\ifblank{#3}{}{\addcomma\space #3}}
{\ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}%
\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
{\addcomma\space}
{}}
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to change bibliography as well or just `\parencite` ? If you modify `mkbibnamefirst` and so on, you will also modify the bibliography.
Also, a full MWE, i.e. one with `\begin{document}` etc. would be quite helpful.

Comment: Yes, it's just \parencite. Behavior in the bibliography looks ok. I don't want \textcite to change.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `DeclareNameFormat...` ? `#3` is the author firstname, what are you trying to do there ? `MakeUppercase` in that context seems superfluous given the earlier definition.

Comment: DeclareNameFormat was supposed to turn into uppercase last names in bibliography.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know what the `historian` style is (it's not a standard one), but I see you use `citestyle=authoryear` anyway, so this should be the same.

The example below does what you want, I believe. It uses the `biblatex` example bibliography. Note that some years have letters after them, this happens when the same author has several works in the same year.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
% \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
% \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
% \renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
% \renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}


\newbibmacro*{cite_p}{%adapted from authoryear.cbx
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
       {\printnames[labelname_p]{labelname}%
        \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
     \iffieldundef{pages}%
         {}%
         {\addcomma\addspace\printfield{pages}}%
   }
   {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]%adapted from authoryear.cbx
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite_p}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname_p}{%from biblatex.def
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:last}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{test.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Year and pages \parencite{nietzsche:historie}.
\item Two inbook with year and pages \parencite{nietzsche:historie, brandt} 
\item A book with no pages \parencite{massa}
\item textcite on a book with no pages \textcite{massa}.
\item Several books \parencite{murray, augustine, cotton, bertram, massa}.
\item Article with single page \parencite{art1}
\item textciting  \textcite{nietzsche:historie, brandt}
\end{itemize}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Explanation**

If you want to know the nitty gritty, compare what I have here with what's in `authoryear.cbx`, you should see what I changed. However, in short:

1. `\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}` to make sure name and year are separated by a space and a comma
2. Made new citation macro `cite_p`, basically a copy of `cite`, but added the pages bit at the end
3. Redefine `parencite` to use our custom `cite_p`.
4. 3+4 ensure that other citation commands are unchanged.

---

**Update**

Fixed some bugs, as per comments below

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works just fine. However, I needed the textcite command to remain the same, namely: "Author (year)." (author not in uppercase). But that's fine. The "historian" style is used just because it puts years where I want them: as the last part of the bibliography entry, and not like "Surname, Name (2000)." What the historian style does (in the bibliography) is "Surname, Name. Title (italics). Place: Publisher, Year."

Comment: I have just found that in the bibliography, last names *and* first names are in uppercase, so I just commented: %\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
%\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

Comment: @Joseph I edited the code, it should now only uppercase the last name of authors that are `\parencite`d.

Comment: That's great ach! I just commented out the code \printfield{pages} (just want total page range in articles etc. to show in the bibliography, as usual).

Comment: Only one caveat: as you can see above, there is a space between the year and the parenthesis in (MASSA, 2004 ). And in all other citations when I remove \addcomma\addspace\printfield{pages}. I couldn't figure out what is causing this space.

Comment: @Joseph I forgot to kill (usign %) some whitespaces in the redefinitionof `cite_p`. Should be fixed now. A good illustration of the dangers of whitespaces in TeX :)

Comment: works fine now!

Comment: The solution above, which used to work fine, doesn't work anymore with the latest (3.4) `biblatex`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're making only small changes to an existing citation command, the `\AtNextCite` hook comes in handy:

```
\let\origparencite\parencite
\let\origparencites\parencites

\newrobustcmd*{\parencitehook}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{##1}}}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\parencite}{\parencitehook\origparencite}
\renewrobustcmd*{\parencites}{\parencitehook\origparencites}
```

The advantage to this approach is that it should work for any of the author-year styles.

Comment: your solution works nice, too.