# biblatex creating cite command (author, year, page(s) )

Tags: biblatex

Is there a command for citing in `biblatex` that somewhat can do what `\citeauthor` does but with a little bit more. I am looking for something like `\cite[85-86][2017]{mehlich2017}`. So the output is something like

> (Mehlich, 2017, p. 85-86)

Or that it can take the year itself from the `biblatex` eintry so its just `\cite[85-86]{mehlich2017}`. I tried looking at the documentation, but I am not sure how I would create a command, since I don't seem to find one that does what I need.

I am using `biblatex` and the `memoir` class and currently using this basic setup (I've used this for quite some time, and I don't think its this one creating problems). Thanks in advance.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,openright,oneside,british,a4paper]{memoir}

%  Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{import}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  style=chem-acs,  % Citation style as (AUTHOR YEAR)
  sorting=none,            % Sort citations as YEAR-NAME-TITLE
  sortcites=true,
  %dashed=false,
  maxcitenames=3,         % Increase/decrease to include more/fewer authors in cites
  maxbibnames=5,          % As above, but in the bibliography
  uniquelist=false,
  uniquename=false,
  doi=false,
  isbn=false,
  eprint=false,
  autocite=superscript,
  biblabel=brackets,
  hyperref=true]{biblatex}

%\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}




\title{Your Paper}
\author{Me}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Your introduction goes here! Simply start writing your document and use the Recompile button to view the updated PDF preview \parencite[85]{mehlich2017}

\end{document}
```

Comment: well you can define all sort of citation commands. But don't you get this already with \parencite?

Comment: Hello. No \parencite just creates [1, p 85] sadly

Comment: well you didn't provide a full example, so I didn't test, but the comment beside the style says `Citation style as (AUTHOR YEAR)`. If it is a numeric style, you should perhaps switch to authoryear instead.

Comment: As always here, it is best to include a complete example with your question that shows your problem and that people can run on their end to recreate it and test solutions.

Comment: @schtandard I've attached a quick example, but I don't think its what I use, I was more just asking if it were a command that could do (author, year, page(s) ) when citing. I am aware of \citeauthor and the likes, but nothing in the documentation (that I could find) that matched that style :)
EDIT: Tried removing everything in the options for biblatex, so it were just \usepackage{biblatex} - same result.

Comment: `style=chem-acs,` selects a numeric citation style, so that most 'normal' `\...cite` commands produce output based on a numeric designation for your sources. If you want author-year citations, you should probably look into using a different style. Try `style=authoryear,` and use the `\autocite` command. Because different styles support different options, I suggest you start small and replace your whole `biblatex` loading block with `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}` (then add options as needed).

Comment: @JonasDenmark Thanks for providing an example. However, I still can't test this as I don't have `bibliography.bib`. See [this answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/48973) for how to include it in your MWE.

Comment: The bibliography.bib just contained a very default article entry to test, nothing else. @moewe it worked as you mentioned by adding ```style=authoryear into the options for \usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}``` which created (Mehlich et al, 2017, p. 85) by using the \parencite. Great, it was just that little difference in style. Though I am surprised this isn't the default method by just using \usepackage{backend=biber]{biblatex} when I tried that. Anyways, thanks for all the help :) I am quite new here, so I appreciate it all with creating MWE and such. Have a nice day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style [`chem-acs`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chem/biblatex-chem-acs.pdf) (of the [`biblatex-chem` bundle](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chem)) is a numeric style. That means that the works in the reference list/bibliography are identified by numeric labels. Hence, most 'normal' `\...cite` commands produce numbers with this style. Of course style-independent commands like `\citeauthor` (cf. §3.9.5 *Text Commands* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)) will still do what the usually do.

**If you want to cite using author-year labels, I suggest you use an author-year style instead of a custom command with a numeric style. The simplest author-year style for `biblatex` is probably `authoryear`.**

Since not all options of `chem-acs` are supported by `authoryear` and it is not clear if you need all of the options that are loaded in the example document anyway, I suggest you simply load `biblatex` as `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}` and add further options as needed.

For citing I suggest you use `\autocite` and `\textcite`. For specialist use you can try all the other commands listed in §3.9 *Citation Commands*.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380-381]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[12]{worman}
dolor \autocite{sigfridsson}
sit \autocite{nussbaum}

But then \textcite{sigfridsson} showed that \dots

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, pp. 380–381) ipsum (Worman 2002, p. 12) dolor (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) sit (Nussbaum 1978) But then Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998) showed that ...]

---

As to why loading `biblatex` just as `\usepackage{biblatex}` did not get you a lot further: That is because if you don't specify a `style` option, `biblatex` defaults to `style=numeric,` which broadly behaves like `chem-acs`.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot more sense! Thanks a lot for the clear message :-).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

One answer in [change authoryear biblatex citation style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117292/change-authoryear-biblatex-citation-style/117332#117332) could be adapted for your purpose

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright,oneside,british,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
    
% ===== Patch citation commands to include entire label in the citation link =====
% BEGIN_FOLD
    
    % Define the delimiter between name and year
    \renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}
    
    % Define new bib macro
    \newbibmacro*{cite_p}{%adapted from authoryear.cbx
        \iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
            {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
                \setunit{\addspace}}%
            {\printnames[labelname_p]{labelname}%
                \setunit{\nameyeardelim}}%
            \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
            \iffieldundef{pages}%
            {}%
            {}%
        }
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    
    % Redefine \parencite
    \DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]%adapted from authoryear.cbx
    {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
        \usebibmacro{cite_p}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
    
    % Modify the string pp.
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
        page={p\adddot},%
        pages={p\adddot},%
    }

% END_FOLD


\begin{document}
    
    \noindent This is sample citation label using \verb|\parencite| \parencite[85-86]{aksin}
    
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```